# Questions about installing an electrical subpanel (re: wire size, etc)

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

My current electrical panel is filled and I'm going to have a pool installed this year so I need to install a subpanel.  (my current box doesn't support tandem breakers, etc)

Because I only need more space (and don't need it in a different location/building), I'm going to place the subpanel a few feet away from the main panel.

What do I need to know before installing it?

- Do I need it a certain distance away from the main panel?
- Can I have the sub-panel behind the main air duct off the furnace?
- What size wire do I need?  The only loads I will have is an above ground pool (pump, filter, gas pool heater) and one or two circuits moved from the main panel to the subpanel so I can connect the subpanel to the filled main panel.

I still have some research to do, but I'm thinking 8/3 wire with a 40A breaker?

Comment: Sounds like "having a full panel" is not a fun experience.  How soon would you like to have that experience again?  Here on this stack, we're fond of the answer "never", and see "avoiding that" as quite a good use of capital.  Not that we're talking a lot of capital...

Comment: Unfortunately the panel was pull when I bought the house so I'm stuck in the situation I'm in.

Comment: You're not stuck in this situation. You can replace your main panel, typically with ease. Could you post some pictures of it? Ideally, we'd get to see the service entry, branch circuits, and the instruction label (hopefully with the model number).

Comment: How much clearance is there between the wall the panel's going on and the main air duct? Also, is the existing panel set into the wall (flush mount) or sticking out from the wall (surface mount), and what wiring method is used for the wires connecting to the existing panel?